# How to get data.txt and attributes.txt and mapping.sql to a Relational Database

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, database-design, mdf

I am trying to create a MDF (Microsoft SQL Server Database) from some files located at http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/census1990-mld/

Can anyone help me with the steps to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend importing the data into a new database.  Open up SQL Server Management Studio, create a new database and then decide how you would like to import the data.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to right click the db in Management Studio - Tasks -> Import data... choose your flat file in the wizard and then choose your mappings.

Another option would be using SSIS packages. They aren't too hard to learn but harder than the previous option and more for repeatable processes.  [This article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1207/different-options-for-importing-data-into-sql-server/)  has quite a few alternative solutions as well.